# I have an incomplete physical encrypted iPhone backup that quit halfway through. Can I rebuild it with pieces from a complete backup?

Tags: iphone, backup, encryption, plist

I have an iPhone 6s running iOS 13.5.x, it was in the middle of a physical backup to my MacBook Pro when the iPhone started to bootloop (shortage of memory, Error 14).

I have half of a complete backup. **It is encrypted**. I don't care about anything except the "On My iPhone" notes, i.e. not backed up anywhere. It is file "4f98687d8ab0d6d1a371110e6b7300f6e465bef2" buried in the folder structure. It looks like it is complete.

I have cross referenced this partial backup to that of three complete backups to the same device / same serial and have found **two issues:**

- 1. the partial backup is in a folder called "snapshot" which seems to be specific to incomplete backups. It is in the top folder, named as a combination of numbers and letters specific to this iPhone, which leads to the bigger issue:
- 2. the partial backup is missing THREE of what I seem to be **FOUR KEY FILES** to decryption:

1. info.plist
2. Manifest.db
3. Manifest.plist
4. Status.plist

In the partial backup **IS** the Status.plist file, but not the other three. Is there any way I can take the three files from another physical backup (same device / same serial / same everything) and get them to work in decrypting this one Notes master file?

Or maybe take info from the "Status.plist" from the incomplete backup to rebuild the four files from a previous backup and use them together in the partial backup? Someone I spoke to mentioned that if the date information is consistent between the four files and the backup it could work, but I wanted to check here to see if the keybags would be consistent or not, if anyone knows that.

If not, is it because the keys change for each backup? **Even if it is the same iPhone / same device TO the same laptop?**

I have already attempted to take the "snapshot" folder and make it the top folder, renaming it the number/letter combination specific to the iPhone. I will note, **the number/letter combination top folder is the same for all backups of this iPhone, making me think it is a unique name to this iPhone/serial.**

When I did the above paragraph, I tried once with all four files from a previous backup. Then the Status.plist from the partial backup WITH the other three from the most recent complete backup. Both were not recognizable backups to restore to from iTunes.

But that doesn't necessarily mean it won't work. It may mean I'm doing it wrong or missed a step.

If I am going down the wrong path, can you think of any other workaround to get just this one Notes master filed decrypted? No it's not on iCloud. No it couldn't be anywhere else, except on the physical iPhone, which is still intact (NOT restored), but bootlooped due to Error 14 (full storage, yes I know I am stupid).